# Are std::atomic loads and stores both required?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, interrupt, atomic

According to [this article](https://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/):

> Any time two threads operate on a shared variable concurrently, and one of those operations performs a write, both threads must use atomic operations.

However, if a lower-priority thread is the writer, and a higher-priority thread is the reader, does the lower-priority thread need to enforce atomic stores?  It seems to me that only the higher-priority thread needs to enforce an atomic load:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<T*> ptr; // assume initialized to some non-null value

void highPriThreadFcn(void)
{
    T* local_ptr = ptr.load(); // need atomic load here in case lowPriThread write/store was interrupted
}

void lowPriThreadFcn(T* some_ptr)
{
    ptr = some_ptr; // do I need an atomic store here? I'd think not, as ptr is not written to by highPriThread
}
```

A similar question would apply in the "reverse" case (write in high-priority thread, read from low-priority thread):

```
void highPriThreadFcn(T* some_ptr)
{
    ptr = some_ptr; // do I need an atomic store here? I'd think not, as write to ptr cannot be interrupted
}

void lowPriThreadFcn(void)
{
    T* local_ptr = ptr.load(); // need atomic load here in case read/load was interrupted
}
```

Comment: When you talk about priority, do you mean the timeslots given to different threads by the OS scheduler? If so, why would that matter? That priority can be changed while the program is running to make the low prio thread into the higher prio thread. Also, you seem to load/store a pointer atomically but how are you accessing the data it's pointing at?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Regarding your first two questions, I guess I am talking about "fixed" priorities (e.g. static priorities assigned in RTOS configuration, or interrupt priorities of CPU).  Regarding the last question, unless it affects the question, I don't see the need to specify, but assume that the pointer will be de-referenced after a load (which may require memory fence).

Comment: @harold Yes, I am referring to a single-core system with the main program as the "low-priority thread" and asynchronous hardware interrupts as the "higher-priority thread"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot perform a non-atomic store or load on an atomic variable. The API ensures that there is no way to attempt it. Your allegedly "non-atomic store",

```
ptr = some_ptr;
```

is actually an atomic store with sequentially consistent ordering. See [atomic::operator= on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D).

By the way, in case you were thinking about changing the atomic variable to a non-atomic variable on which only some operations are performed atomically: don't do that. Whenever a load and a store to the same memory location are "potentially concurrent", the standard requires that they **both** be atomic. Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined. That means the compiler is allowed to "optimize" in a way that breaks your code. Whether or not a thread is "higher" priority than another doesn't affect this.

Comment: +1 and [std::atomic<T>::operator T](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) for the load counterpart.

Comment: Thanks.  I came upon some info suggesting the same (i.e. that whether or not one explicitly uses .load()/.store(), a read/write of an atomic is still treated as such), but I wasn't making the connection that it applied in this case.

Answer (score -1):

The Standard is designed to be supportable on platforms with weird and bizarre memory semantics.  Too accommodate this, it avoids imposing any requirements upon how implementations handle any constructs which might be hard for some platforms to handle predictably.  Some implementations interpret this as license to behave in arbitrary and unpredictably fashion in such cases *even when targeting platforms that would naturally support stronger memory semantics*.  This facilitates some kinds of optimization, but can make it necessary for programmers to take explicit actions to tie optimizers' hands, in some cases making things less efficient than they could have been if compilers provided (and programmers exploited) stronger semantics than the Standard requires.

As an example of a situation where things might go wrong, consider something like:

```
extern int foo;

int x=foo;
.... some code that modifies neither x nor foo
int y=x;
.... some code that modifies neither y nor foo (but might modify x)
doSomething(x, y);
```

It would be entirely plausible that an optimizing compiler might replace the last function call with `doSomething(x, foo)` on the assumption that `foo` must equal the value that `y` would have had at the time of the original assignment.  Rather than use an abstraction model that would allow for bounded non-determinism, the authors of the Standard simply declined to mandate any sort of behavioral guarantees about the effects of having objects' values change unexpectedly.

Comment: I don't see what the issue with your example is, assuming y is not ```volatile```.  Care to elaborate?  Does it have something to do with "bounded non-determinism" (I don't know what that is)?

Comment: @abc: What supercat proposes is that the compiler moves the read of `foo` much later.  That's important, because `foo` is visible to other code (possibly including ISRs).  If there's a race and `foo` is atomic, the outcome is hard to predict but consistent with a possible ordering.  In this snippet `foo` isn't atomic, so any data race will result in UB.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, I see.  So all read/writes of atomics are implicity atomic loads/stores in case the compiler does some unexpected re-ordering (or optimizing out) of things that might "break" things based on the atomic behavior one was expecting (e.g. if one explicitly called atomic load/store where it ended up not mattering, but failed to make an explicit load/store call where it ended up being necessary due to compiler re-arrangement).

Comment: @abc: In an abstraction model that allowed for bounded non-determinism, reading an object subject to a race condition would yield a non-deteministic value that behaves as a superposition of all values the object could hold, but for types with no trap representations *would have no other side-effects*.  If such an abstraction model provided an intrinsic which, given a possibly-non-deterministic value, would yield a value chosen in Unspecified fashion from among the possible values it could hold, programmers could allow compilers more flexibility than is possible with today's standard.